# Any command to check packets received and transmitted

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, packet-analyzer

Is there any command line option to check how many packets my P.C is receiving and transmitting in real time (something like top) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `iptraf` or `iftop` for network-monitoring.

Just install it with `sudo apt-get install iptraf` or `sudo apt-get install iftop`